# Using a UIImageView to adjust a UIImage

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImage and I want to adjust what is shown on the device based on a UIImageView.

The UIImage is:

```
UIImage *image = // a PNG I have

// width = 1200
CGFloat width = image.size.width;

// height = 900
CGFloat height = image.size.height;
```

And I have an UIImageView

```
UIImageView *iview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 675.0, 900.0)];
```

How do I get my UIImage into the UIImageView without adjust the aspect ratio? I want the UIImage to be cropped off the edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to crop off the edges and center the position of ur image then 
Set the Imageview properties to AspectFill

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; 
myImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps

```
-(UIImage*)crop:(CGRect)frame
{
    // Find the scalefactors  UIImageView's widht and height / UIImage width and height
    CGFloat widthScale = self.bounds.size.width / self.image.size.width;
    CGFloat heightScale = self.bounds.size.height / self.image.size.height;

    // Calculate the right crop rectangle 
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x * (1 / widthScale);
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y * (1 / heightScale);
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width * (1 / widthScale);
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height * (1 / heightScale);

    // Create a new UIImage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.image.CGImage, frame);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return croppedImage;//(return value is uiimage)
}
```

and then add it to uiimageview

Comment: and what's the bounds?

Comment: uiimageview frame and uiview bounds

Comment: so the uiimageview is larger than the uiview or vice versa?

Comment: +1 for effort but I can't get it working quite right with the camera

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `contentMode` property of your UIImageView to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, which according to the documentation is:

```
The option to scale the content to fill the size of the view. Some portion of the 
content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.
```

You can see the other options in the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).